# What position and affiliation to fill in a conference application in a situation like this?

Tags: conference

I'm going to apply for participation in a conference that happens in July. In the application they ask for my position and affiliation. The important point is that right now I'm a PhD student at a university and by July I'm going to be a postdoc in another university.

In that regard, I'm not sure how to fill the information. The reason I feel this is relevant is twofold: (1) I think they are more likely to accept the application from a postdoc than a PhD student, (2) the university I'm in right now is not very known in the field, whereas the one I'm going to is, and maybe this also impacts the application being accepted.

In that case:

1. Should I just fill my current position and affiliation, and in the "additional comments" field explain that by the time of the conference I'll be in another position somewhere else
2. Or should I just fill the position and affiliation I'll have by the time the conference takes place?

Comment: As a general norm, it is expected that in most applications, one provides the information pertaining to current state (unless explicitly asked for a possible future state), for the simple reason that we do not know for certain that the future event will happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The information will likely be used to label your badge at the conference, not to make decisions about acceptance.

I think it isn't very important; if it were me, I'd just put down my current information. Though you've been hired to a post doc, you haven't actually started it yet, so to me it seems like the risk of advertising yourself as having an affiliation you don't really have yet is greater than the hardly existent benefit.

If you're presenting, you can note your current affiliation at the time of presentation on your poster or slides. I am recalling I've also seen people scribble alternate details on their conference badges - my first thought when encountering someone who's scribbled on a ", PhD! :)" after their name would be to say "congratulations!" as it likely indicates they've graduated recently, some time between registration and the actual conference.

Alternatively, you could simply ask them. State your situation simply: that you're currently a graduate student at X and at the time of the conference you'll be a post doc at Y, and ask which is more appropriate to give. Shouldn't be more than two sentences.